# Rest Api Query filter

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am  trying to query data from my List and it working properly using rest api, but when I tried using filter in my uri against a column that is a checkbox no results showed

```
https://mySharepoint/sites/subsite/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MainList')/Items?$select=Title&$filter=(CheckboxColumn eq 'Africa')
```

I have read that you cannot use filter against a multi select column using rest api, but I believe you may use "_vti_bin/listdata.svc" but I wanted to make sure first that "filter" in rest api is not applicable when used in Multi select column

Comment: Filter in REST api should work. I just created a new choice column with allowed multiple selection and it worked with your rest query filter `https://sharepointO365/sites/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/Items?$select=Title&$filter=(CheckboxColumn eq 'Africa')`. It doesn't matter if the list item has 1 selection (Africa) or multiple selected options (Africa, USA) in the CheckboxColumn.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can very well use filter on checkboxes(muliple selection choice field).

It will always return the items where the filtered choice is selected.

I tried below url both on SharePoint 2013 on premise and SharePoint online and it is working fine(directly in browser tab). try this url:

```
https://mySharepoint/sites/subsite/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainList')/items?$select=Title,CheckboxColumn&$filter=CheckboxColumn eq 'Africa'
```

Comment: Oh it was really working in API, I was mislead by the post I read :(

Comment: How can you filter through multiple parameters?

Comment: What do you mean of multiple parameters?filter on Multiple values for same column or filter on multiple columns?